# basic question in foreach in php

Tags: php

basically if I have a string like this:

$str = \data1\data2\data3\data_tmp\file.pgp

can anyone tell me how to get the last part 'file.pgp'?

TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$last = array_pop(explode('\\', $str));
```

You don't need `foreach` for that. It's used when you have to iterate through the whole collection (in your case, array).

If you need to get the remaining part of the string:

```
$segments = explode('\\', $str);
$last = array_pop($segments);
```

It will be in `$segments`, as an array. If you want to convert it back to a string, then use `join('\\', $segments)`. However, if this is a Windows path and you're running PHP on Windows, then you should be using the `basename` and `dirname` functions.

Comment: thank you. can you tell me is there any way to get the remaining bit excluding the last bit?

Answer (score 6):

You are looking for the [`basename()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function.

This function takes a file path and returns the file name *without the suffix* (the final part of your file name that specifies its type)

Comment: Interestingly, seems like that's only going to work in a windows environment, as per here:

http://codepad.org/XjiPZWeu

Comment: @Tchalvak, that behavior is actually documented in the PHP documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php

Comment: It will work in other environments, but only if the normal system separator is used.  See: http://codepad.org/dLIPlp2R and this quote from the php manual: "On Windows, both slash (/) and backslash (\\) are used as directory separator character. In other environments, it is the forward slash (/)."

Comment: @Ignas R ... Thanks!  (Sorry for posting the same information, I didn't see your comment until after I had posted mine.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) will give you what you need

if that doesn't do it try

```
$path = str_replace('\\', '/', $path)
```

first